# In how many ways can a candidate choose questions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are three sections in a question paper, each having $5$ questions. A candidate has to solve $5$ questions in total, selecting at least one from each section. In how many ways can he do this?.

I have explicitly made cases and computed the answer, but how do I do it without making cases like $1,2,2$, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: There are only $2$ cases: 1,1,3 and 1,2,2 (and a multiplication factor of 3 to account for other orders).

Comment: @quasi yeah exactly i did this way. but whats problem in doing as $5^3 C(12,2)$

Comment: Besides the fact that $5^3C(12,2)$ gives the wrong answer? What reasoning would you propose to support that calculation?

Comment: @quasi $5^3$ ways to choose 1 question from each section, then $12 \choose 2$ to pick the others, I suppose.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma -- Ok, I see his idea. But then each quintuple is counted more than once. Some are counted 3 times, some are counted 4 times.

Comment: @quasi Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @J. Deff -- My updated answer explains the issue with regard to your proposed count of $$(5^3){\small{\binom{12}{2}}}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $2$ questions are chosen from some section, then the split must be $1,2,2$ in some order, hence the number of ways is
$$(3)\binom{5}{1}\binom{5}{2}^2 = (3)(5)(10^2)=1500$$
If $3$ questions are chosen from some section, then the split must be $1,1,3$ in some order, hence the number of ways is
$$(3)\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{1}^2=(2)(10)(5^2)=750$$
so the total is $1500+750=2250$.

So while that's the correct answer, you asked why the count couldn't instead be computed  as

$$(5^3){\small{\binom{12}{2}}}$$

Presumably, as Henno Brandsma suggested, your explanation as to why the above product should yield the desired count is something along these lines:

- The factor $5^3$ represents the number of ways to choose one problem from each section.

  The factor $\large{\binom{12}{2}}$ represents the number of ways to choose the remaining two problems.

So what's wrong with that?

Firstly, it would yield the wrong answer; $8250$, instead of the correct answer, $2250$.

But where's the logical error? Doesn't the $(5^3){\large{\binom{12}{2}}}$ count allow for every possible legal set of $5$ problem choices?

Yes, but it's an overcount. Some sets are counted $4$ times; some are counted $3$ times.

An example of each type . . .

Let the sections be denoted $A,B,C$.

For $1\le k \le5$, and $X \in\{A,B,C\}$, let $X_k$ denote the $k$-th problem in section $X$.

For example, $B_4$ denotes problem $4$ of section $B$.

Then in the $(5^3){\large{\binom{12}{2}}}$ count, the set $\{A_1,B_1,B_2,C_1,C_2\}$ is counted $4$ times:

\begin{align*}
{\small\bullet}\;\;&\text{First choose}\,\{A_1,B_1,C_1\},\,\text{then choose}\;\{B_2,C_2\}\\[4pt]
{\small\bullet}\;\;&\text{First choose}\,\{A_1,B_1,C_2\},\,\text{then choose}\;\{B_2,C_1\}\\[4pt]
{\small\bullet}\;\;&\text{First choose}\,\{A_1,B_2,C_1\},\,\text{then choose}\;\{B_1,C_2\}\\[4pt]
{\small\bullet}\;\;&\text{First choose}\,\{A_1,B_2,C_2\},\,\text{then choose}\;\{B_1,C_1\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

and the set $\{A_1,B_1,C_1,C_2,C_3\}$ is counted $3$ times:

\begin{align*}
{\small\bullet}\;\;&\text{First choose}\,\{A_1,B_1,C_1\},\,\text{then choose}\;\{C_2,C_3\}\\[4pt]
{\small\bullet}\;\;&\text{First choose}\,\{A_1,B_1,C_2\},\,\text{then choose}\;\{C_1,C_3\}\\[4pt]
{\small\bullet}\;\;&\text{First choose}\,\{A_1,B_1,C_3\},\,\text{then choose}\;\{C_1,C_2\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

There are various ways to correct the overcount, but any correction still needs to consider  the two types of overcounted sets$\,-\,$those counted $4$ times, and those counted $3$ times; in effect, the *same* two cases as in the method shown using the splits $(1,2,2)$ and $(1,1,3)$.

Comment: i think there will be overcounting in the former way you have suggested too

Comment: @J. Deff: I don't follow. Are you claiming that the answer $2250$ is not correct?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe inclusion-exclusion is the way to go.

You have to pick 5 questions out of 15.
Let $S_i$ be the number of choices where the candidate does not choose a question from section $i$.

The total number of options is ${15 \choose 5}$.

Then $|S_i| = {10 \choose 5}$ for each $i$, as we exclude one section of 5 questions.

All intersections $S_i \cap S_j, i \neq j$ have size 1, as we exclude 10 out of 15, and we have to choose 5.

$S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 = \emptyset$ as we must choose some questions so some section is used.

Now the inclusion-exclusion principle tells us that the number of good choices is

$${15 \choose 5} - 3\cdot {10 \choose 5} + 3 \cdot 1 =3003 -3\cdot 252 + 3 =2250$$

(The 3 comes from the fact that there are 3 sets $S_i$ and 3 intersections $S_i \cap S_j$ in total, all the same size, as we saw.

No case distinctions necessary then,and generalisations to more categories are clear and not a lot harder.

Comment: Thanks i will look at this principle. Can you tell me mistake in my attempt if i say choose mandatory questions first from each section in $5^3$ ways and then other two can be selected in C(12,2) ways and then we multiiply. Thanks

Comment: @J.Deff you overcount: suppose you chose 1a,2a, 1b, 2b, 3c from sections a,b,c. Then you count them differently depending on whether 1a / 1b are the compulsory choices or 2a, 2b etc. There is not an easy factor between them, it depends on the distribution. I think inclusion-exclusion wins. See its Wikipedia entry for the formula I applied.

Comment: we;;, i have read about principle but can you tell me why have you coose S i's in that very way

Comment: can you elaborate so that i can see how principle is applied to problems like these

Comment: Look at the WIkipedia entry https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle for the complementary form lower in the page. I compute the intersection of complements (all sets $S_i$ need to be avoided exactly to be a solution to the counting problem at hand).@J.Deff